# JSSOR Thumbnail navigator goes to wrong slide when $DisplayPieces is set to 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jssor

Having this strange bug where when I set $DisplayPieces to 2, the second row of thumbnails (starting with the second thumbnail from the left) when clicked go to the previous thumbnail's slide.

Here's a link to the JSSOR slider in question: http://antony.dreamhosters.com/our-team.html

When I set $DisplayPieces to 1 it works fine. The arrow navigator works fine. And when auto-played it works fine.

Any idea what could be causing this, or suggestions for debugging further.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am working on this now. Will update you soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fixed the bug, please download the latest version.

Note name changes of the new version,

```
$DirectionNavigatorOptions -> $ArrowNavigatorOptions
$JssorDirectionNavigator$ -> $JssorArrowNavigator$

$JssorNavigatorOptions -> $BulletNavigatorOptions
$JssorNavigator$ -> $JssorBulletNavigator$
```

Comment: Works perfect now. Thanks so much!

Is there a donation option on jssor.com or another way the we can help support the project?